# How to select average of count in SQL with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
-----------------
| Branch        |
-----------------
| BCODE | BNAME |
|1      | City1 |
|2      | City2 |
-----------------

-----------------------
| Customer            |
-----------------------
| CNO | CNAME | BCODE |
-----------------------
|1    | Cust1 | 1     |
|2    | Cust2 | 1     |
|3    | Cust3 | 2     |
|4    | Cust4 | 2     |
|5    | Cust5 | 2     |
|6    | Cust6 | 2     |
-----------------------
```

What I want : list of branches that have less customers than the average number of customers for each branch

What I tried (closest to the answer):

```
SELECT bcode, bname, customers from (
    SELECT 
        branch.BCODE as bcode, 
        branch.BNAME as bname ,
        count(customer.BCODE)as customers, 
        (select 
            count(customer.BCODE)/count(distinct customer.BCODE) 
        from customer) as average 
    FROM 
        branch 
    INNER JOIN
        customer 
    ON 
        branch.BCODE=customer.BCODE
    GROUP BY 
        branch.BCODE,
        branch.BNAME
    ) 
WHERE 
    average > customers;
```

What I got :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
> average > accounts LIMIT 0, 25' at line 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem occurs at end of the sub-query because you don't have an alias.

```
SELECT bcode, bname, customers from (
    SELECT 
        branch.BCODE as bcode, 
        branch.BNAME as bname ,
        count(customer.BCODE)as customers, 
        (select 
            count(customer.BCODE)/count(distinct customer.BCODE) 
        from customer) as average 
    FROM 
        branch 
    INNER JOIN
        customer 
    ON 
        branch.BCODE=customer.BCODE
    GROUP BY 
        branch.BCODE,
        branch.BNAME
    ) a  -- Alias here
WHERE 
    average > customers;
```

Check on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1925560d4c52d9f9d74ddfe84ca4c14) and pay attention on 18th row.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have specified seems to be a syntax error from a previous execution, however, your query was giving different errors for derived tables. try below query

```
SELECT bcode, bname, customers 
from (  SELECT 
        branch.BCODE as bcode, 
        branch.BNAME as bname ,
        count(customer.BCODE)as customers, 
        (select count(customer.BCODE)/count(distinct customer.BCODE) as avg from customer) average 
        FROM  branch 
          INNER JOIN customer 
          ON branch.BCODE=customer.BCODE
          GROUP BY branch.BCODE,branch.BNAME)cust
         WHERE 
         cust.average > cust.customers;
```

try out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e9e3/6

Comment: yes, i formatted the code to make the post more readable :), thank you, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I *strongly* recommend using window functions:

```
SELECT bcode, bname, customers 
FROM (SELECT b.BCODE, b.BNAME,
             COUNT(c.BCODE) as customers, 
             AVG(COUNT(c.BCODE)) OVER () as avg_customers
      FROM branch b JOIN
           customer  c
           ON b.BCODE = c.BCODE
      GROUP BY b.BCODE, b.BNAME
     ) bc  -- Alias here
WHERE customers < avg_customers;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- This uses table aliases, which makes the query easier to write and to read.
- The default alias for `b.BCODE` **is** `bcode`.  There is no need to use `as`.